# Adding two columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns in an excel sheet called numOne and numTwo as follows:

```
numOne  numTwo
1       2
2       3
3       6
4       7
```

Now I want to write a VBA macro(automate) to add these columns and create a third column numSum
How can I achive that?
The output should look like this :

```
 numOne  numTwo  numSum
1       2        3
2       3        5
3       6        9
4       7        11
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there. Normally people don't ask for a ready code here. You should at least try something yourself and then ask for a solution to your *specific problem* if one occurs.

Comment: OK will post it here in a while.

Comment: why do you need code for it? can't you just do a formula `C2=A2+B2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are lying into the columns 1 and 2 of your spreadsheet, starting from the 2nd row, you can achieve the purpose like this (even if an Excel formula would be much more reasonable):

```
Sub numSum()
Dim count As Integer: count = 0
Cells(1,3) = "numSum"
Do While Cells(1,count + 2) <> ""
    Cells(3,count+2) = Cells(1,count+2) + Cells(2,count+2)
    count = count + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

...which is a "pure" VBA approach to the problem, i.e. there will be only hard-coded data in your spreadsheet without adding any formula to the cells.

Comment: I had tried the same code but instead of Do while condtion checking for a "" I was checking for a NULL which was giving me a Type Mismatch error

Comment: @AmanMathur, `null` is an object type, that in VBA syntax has the keyword `Nothing` (that's why "type mismatch"). Your loop looks at cells values: the cell is an object, the value is a property of the cell. In general, keep clear this distinction when writing your codes. This was not a big deal since the code does not compile, but sometimes the same kind of mistakes might lead to a code which compiles but has a deep conceptual mistake leading to wrong results/behaviors. P.s. consider marking the answer if it's at your satisfaction ;)

Comment: Other trick: if you would write `Do While Cells <> 0`, in your specific example it would work as well. However, like this you risk that a 0 is legally present into your dataset and the loop will stop when it finds this value. Hence, always better to use the condition `Do While Cells <> ""`, so you know that the break of the loop will occur only if the cell is completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

As vba4all says you could easily do this with a formula but to do this with VBA you could try:

```
Sub test()
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & LastRow)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add up, let’s say columns “A” and “B” into column “D”:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“YourSheet”).Columns(“D”).FormulaArray = “=C[-3]+C[-2]”`

How this syntax works:

- Choose your result column (here: column D)
- Refer to the columns you want to add up by not by their name, but by where they are from your result column. C[-2] means the second column to the left, C[5] would mean the fifth column to the right and so on. The “C” in “C[-2]” means “column”.
- You can add up as many columns as you’d like

The same syntax for rows:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“YourSheet”).Rows(“4”).FormulaArray = “=R[-3]+R[-2]”`

And, for blocks:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“YourSheet”).Range(“C1:C3”).FormulaArray = “=RC[-2]:R[3]C[-2]+RC[-1]:R[3]C[-1]”`

For C1:C3 = A1:A3 + B1:B3.
The “same row, two columns to the right” is referred to as RC[2] instead of R[0]C[2].

Good luck :)